# Using row ID to delete rows in a loop 'Cannot read property 'remove' of null'

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, for-loop

I have a script that adds and subtracts rows from a table. As I add new rows, I assign the row ID a number. And when I subtract rows, I decrease that number. When I decide to select a row to delete, I delete the row by using the ID number.

I am stuck on one function 'clearfields' that is supposed to clear all rows up to row 11 when a button is pushed. In my loop I am going from a start point of 12 to the end of the table length.

My issue is if I delete a row sort of in the middle lets say row 18 out of 22, I get a remove null error when the button is pushed and I run this function. Any way around this? Can I just delete all rows no matter what the ID is up until a row ID of 11 is reached?Any help is most appreciated. Thanks

Javascript

```
function clearFields(){ 
        buttonLim=0;
        var tableClr = document.getElementById('table2').rows.length;
        var subJob=tableClr;
        var subJob2=tableClr-10;
        var numb=11;
        var getter= $("#num1").val();
         i=11;
            for (var i = 0; i <= tableClr-1; i++) {// this is where I empty the cells

            var adde=i+4;        
             $("#num"+adde+"Sun").val("");
             $("#num"+adde+"Mon").val("");
             $("#num"+adde+"Tue").val("");
             $("#num"+adde+"Wed").val("");
             $("#num"+adde+"Thu").val("");
             $("#num"+adde+"Fri").val("");
             $("#num"+adde+"Sat").val("");       
             added=0;


        }       
        if(tableClr>11){ //comment here... this is where I delete the rows
        for (var j = 12; j <= tableClr; j++) {          
                 document.getElementById("row" + j).remove(); 

            }           
    } 

     else
       {
       }
    }
```

Comment: check for null here: `document.getElementById("row" + j).remove(); `

Comment: Create a JSFiddle please

Comment: If you'll remove `=` from the condition of `j`-loop, what happens?  `tableClr` is equal to the length of the collection, the last index is `tableClr -1`, as you've noticed in `i`-loop.

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { $("#table2 tr").html("") }`

Comment: @Daniel how do I check for null there?

Comment: We need to see your HTML, you probably don't have items with such `id` here `document.getElementById("row" + j)`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the for loop variables and their constraints i am no expert but i get a feeling that your problem might be solved when you correct the for loop with different variables and conditions(just give var to j not like a number(12) and update the var) see what i am saying just relax and try after a bit you'll figure it out for yourself, it happens with me at all the times.